# SwiftUI - Display content (ads) after Nth element in array

Tags: swiftui

So I'm iterating over items in an array, I wish to display an ad say after every 3 or if the current index is divisble/a multiple of 3.

```
  if !homeViewModel.posts.isEmpty {
       ForEach(homeViewModel.posts, id: \.postID) { post in
          HeaderCell(post: post)
              GADNativeViewControllerWrapper()
                       .frame(height: 250)
                       .padding(10)
}
```

Yes, I am aware I will be showing an ad after every cell but I have tried iterating over the `.indicies` which has more of less given me the same result. How do I get the curreny index of `post in` and check it's position in the array?

I'm just lost here right now, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with tried iterationg over the `.indices`? Why didn't it work? Because thats the solution to your problem...

Comment: @Ali Basically, it would seem to append/show the advert after all items have been displayed. So at the bottom of the first ForEach statement. I put it inside the ForEach statement and it shows under every cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display an ad every 3rd element in an array you need to iterate over the `.indices` and conditionally display content based on the current index.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let posts = [1,2,3,4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(posts.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                HStack {
                    Text("Index: \(index)").bold()
                    Text("Post: \(posts[index])")
                }

                if (index + 1) % 3 == 0 {
                    Rectangle().fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(height: 30)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: The thing is I'm using a PostModel so whilst I can get the Int value I cannot extract the post within the homeViewMode.posts array to display.

Comment: You can still do `homeViewModel.posts[index]` to get the post

Comment: thank you so much! You beautiful programmer!